# How to unpack just a file libffmpeg.so without folders and subfolders in the terminal from .pkg.tar.zst in Debian 11?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, chromium, opera, zstd

Installed on Debian 11 Bullseye opera-stable_80.0.4170.72.
There is no chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra package and the video is not played on Facebook and Twitter.

```
# Launching the terminal
# Installing the archiver
sudo apt install zstd
# Creating a folder
mkdir ${HOME}/ffmpeg-codecs && cd ffmpeg-codecs
# Downloading the package
wget https://archlinux.thaller.ws/community/os/x86_64/opera-ffmpeg-codecs-94.0.4606.81-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
# I'm looking at the location of the file in the package
tar -I zstd -tf opera-ffmpeg-codecs-94.0.4606.81-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst | grep libffmpeg.so
command output: usr/lib/opera/lib_extra/libffmpeg.so
# For unpacking libffmpeg.so I use Midnight Commander
# Checking dependencies
ldd libffmpeg.so
# making a backup copy
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so.bak
# creating a soft link
sudo ln -sf ${HOME}/ffmpeg-codecs/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/libffmpeg.so
Now the video is playing!
```

My question:
How to unpack only the file libffmpeg.so without folders and subfolders from the terminal with the command:

```
tar -I zstd -xvf opera-ffmpeg-codecs-94.0.4606.81-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided the question myself. I read the documents on the link

```
https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/transform.html
document section
‘--strip-components=number’
Strip given number of leading components from file names before extraction.
```

I looked at the structure of the archive

```
tar -I zstd -tf opera-ffmpeg-codecs-94.0.4606.81-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzgHU.png)

Unpacked libffmpeg.so to the folder ${HOME}/ffmpeg-codecs

```
tar -I zstd -xvf opera-ffmpeg-codecs-94.0.4606.81-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst --strip=4 usr/lib/opera/lib_extra/libffmpeg.so
```

[lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYv0F.png)

The question can be closed.